How can I concatenate videos that don't always have audio using ffmpeg?
I have 5 video files (although, it could be 100s), some with audio, some without.  They are more-or-less a consistent size but I'll force that by using something like -vf "320:240" on the command line (dealing with SAR and DAR I'll leave to another time... Ugh).
The objective is to concatenate the videos together to form one video.
I've had a look at http://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/Concatenate#extscript but I haven't been able to get the external source file listing video input method to work reliably.  This.. and having considered various other (inconsistent and complicated) sources, including the official docs, has led me to thinking the following might work:
# combine.txt - a -filter_complex script for concatenting videos
#

# Setup the files and their video & audio streams:
[in0:v] = [in0:a] = movie("sample0.mp4")
[in1:v] = movie("sample1.mp4")
[in2:v] = [in2:a] = movie("sample2.mp4")
[in3:v] = movie("sample3.mp4")
[in4:v] = movie("sample4.mp4")

# Select the video streams from each video file
[0:v] [1:v] [2:v] [3:v] [4:v];

# Join all the video streams into one stream
[in] concat=n:v:a=0 [concat_v];

# Video is done, now select the audio streams
[0:a] [2:a];

# Join all the audio streams into one stream
[in] concat=n:v=0:a [concat_a];

# Send the video and audio streams to the output
[concat_a] [concat_v] output

# [eof]

...and I'd use the script with something like:
ffmpeg -filter_complex_script "combine.txt" -vf "320:240" -y "output.mp4"

I've verified the files are such that they have the audio streams as specified, they are all in the current default directory, as is the script file... but I variously get errors thrown that are variable, mostly cryptic and/or unhelpful.
Thus, I thought I'd see if folks here might be able to 'ball park' examine what I'm trying to do and then, at least, I wouldn't be exploring in total darkness.
Ultimately, I intend to write a script (using Perl, Python, etc) that will create the -filter_complex text file, so I want to establish a 'general approach' or logic so I can scale-up the processing.
I am (currently) needing to do this under Windows 8.1 32-bit (hence, I have to be mindful of the 8191 character limit for the command line in cmd.exe) and I'm using a downloaded binary build of ffmpeg, ffprobe, etc.
ffmpeg version information:
ffmpeg version n6.0-22-g549430e14d-20230529 Copyright (c) 2000-2023 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 12.2.0 (crosstool-NG 1.25.0.152_89671bf)
configuration: --prefix=/ffbuild/prefix --pkg-config-flags=--static --pkg-config=pkg-config --
cross-prefix=i686-w64-mingw32- --arch=i686 --target-os=mingw32 --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --
disable-debug --disable-w32threads --enable-pthreads --enable-iconv --enable-libxml2 --enable-
zlib --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-gmp --enable-lzma --enable-fontconfig --
enable-libvorbis --enable-opencl --disable-libpulse --enable-libvmaf --disable-libxcb --disable-
xlib --enable-amf --enable-libaom --enable-libaribb24 --enable-avisynth --enable-chromaprint --
enable-libdav1d --disable-libdavs2 --disable-libfdk-aac --enable-ffnvcodec --enable-cuda-llvm --
enable-frei0r --enable-libgme --enable-libkvazaar --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-
libjxl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librist --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora
--enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-lv2 --disable-libmfx --enable-libvpl --enable-openal
--enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg
--enable-libopenmpt --disable-librav1e --enable-librubberband --enable-schannel --enable-sdl2 --
enable-libsoxr --enable-libsrt --disable-libsvtav1 --enable-libtwolame --disable-libuavs3d --
disable-libdrm --disable-vaapi --enable-libvidstab --enable-vulkan --enable-libshaderc --
disable-libplacebo --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --disable-libxavs2 --enable-libxvid --
enable-libzimg --enable-libzvbi --extra-cflags=-DLIBTWOLAME_STATIC --extra-cxxflags= --extra-
ldflags=-pthread --extra-ldexeflags= --extra-libs=-lgomp --extra-version=20230529
libavutil      58.  2.100 / 58.  2.100
libavcodec     60.  3.100 / 60.  3.100
libavformat    60.  3.100 / 60.  3.100
libavdevice    60.  1.100 / 60.  1.100
libavfilter     9.  3.100 /  9.  3.100
libswscale      7.  1.100 /  7.  1.100
libswresample   4. 10.100 /  4. 10.100
libpostproc    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100

I've been spending way too much time trying to get this sorted and it's making me nutz... so, I'd greatly appreciate any suggestions on how to proceed.

If you not sure if a video has audio or not you can use something like; ffmpeg -i input -map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:0?

add silence
#!/bin/bash

cd /tmp
if [ ! -f sample0.mp4 ]; then
#create test files
    for i in 0 2; do
        ffmpeg -lavfi "testsrc2,sine=440" -t 2 "sample${i}.mp4" -v 16
    done
    for i in 1 3 4; do
        ffmpeg -lavfi "testsrc2" -t 2 "sample${i}.mp4" -v 16
    done
fi

lst=(sample*.mp4) # this array can be unsorted
inp=()
echo "" > combine.txt
con=""
wid=360
hei=240
sps="scale=$wid:$hei:force_original_aspect_ratio=decrease,pad=$wid:$hei:-1:-1,setsar=1"
for (( i=0; i<${#lst[@]}; i++ )); do
    f="${lst[$i]}"
    inp+=("-i" "$f")
    echo "[$i:v]$sps[v$i];" >> combine.txt
    dur=$(ffprobe -show_entries format=duration -of default=nw=1:nk=1 "$f" -v 16)
    a=$(ffprobe -select_streams a:0 -show_entries stream=codec_name -of csv=p=0 "$f" -v 16)
    if [[ "$a" != "" ]]; then
        echo "[$i:a]aresample=async=1,apad=whole_dur=$dur,atrim=0:$dur[a$i];" >> combine.txt
    else
        echo "aevalsrc=0:d=$dur[a$i];" >> combine.txt
    fi
    con+="[v$i][a$i]"
done
echo "${con}concat=$i:1:1" >> combine.txt
cat combine.txt
ffmpeg "${inp[@]}" -filter_complex_script "combine.txt" "out.mp4"
# ffmpeg "${inp[@]}" -/filter_complex "combine.txt" "out.mp4"
mpv out.mp4

